# User repeatedly removing main body of a post despite a warning

Tags: discussion, new-users

I noticed on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160051/fourier-1st-step) that the user has removed the body/equation in his main post twice, amid a warning of suspension (as noted in the comments) by  Zev Chonoles. Is there anything I should do beyond editing his post to put his equation and whatnot back in there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you for pointing this out - I've suspended the relevant user. Notifying the moderators and rolling back the destructive edit is all you need to do (you could also leave a comment explaining your reasoning for undoing the edit if you want). Though for the future, this kind of thing is better suited to a moderator flag than a meta post.

Comment: Thank you. I just realized that this  was a bit short for a Meta post, and instead just flagged the post a few minutes ago, sorry. Will note that for the future.

Comment: No problem Joe, I'm always happy to see users participating in the moderation of the site! The main reason I, at least, would prefer a moderator flag only, is that I want to avoid public discussion of any specific user's negative actions; even though they're doing something bad, we (at least usually) want them to feel welcome back after the suspension's up, and a meta post calling attention to them may hinder that.

Comment: Fair enough - makes sense.